# Подскажите пожалуйста как в sed переместить строку?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

**Доброго времени суток!**

Есть некий файл: test.txt

- aaaaaaaaa
- wwwwwwwww
- ccccccccc
- ddddddddd
- eeeeeeeee
- kkkkkkkkk

надо сделать так и сохранить.(к примеру строку №5 переместить на №15)

- aaaaaaaaa
- ccccccccc
- ddddddddd
- eeeeeeeee
- wwwwwwwww
- kkkkkkkkk

P.S. *система OS X, не знаю, имеет значение...*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> к примеру строку №5 переместить на №15

```
sed -e '5{h;d;};15G' -i '' <файл>
```

- `5` — сопоставление адреса строки 5
- `{` — начало блочной команды

  - `h` — сохраняет строку в буфер
  - `d` — удаляет её из вывода
- `}` — конец блочной команды
- `15` — сопоставление строки 15
- `G` — добавляет строку из буфера в конец текущей строки

Comment: конечный результат:

sed -i "" '6{h;d;};18G' test.txt

после d; (bash ругнулся)
в OS X после -i необходимо ставить ""

Comment: разжевал подробно и подправил с учётом BSD"яшного sed'а.

Comment: А как же в обратном порядке это можно зделать?
Допустем с 15 на 5 тую передвинуть?
У меня просто удаляеться пространство 5 той строки а 15 тая ваще удаляеться..